# Build fails in TFS by giving an error "Packages failed to publish"

Tags: tfs, build, nuget, package, nuget-server

When I publish a NuGet to TFS using a build step, I get following error messages:

```
2017-05-26T09:58:26.8605708Z ##[error]Error: d:\a\_tasks\NuGetPublisher_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f25b\0.2.34\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe failed with return code: 1
2017-05-26T09:58:26.8605708Z ##[error]Packages failed to publish
```

[image]

Comment: Found a solution for this and please see the 2nd answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the AssemblyInfo.cs file. There are two lines of code as shown below.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

And change this to this as shown below

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

So that the compiler will set the File Version to be equal to the Product Version. And it automatically increases.

Ex : [image]

And finally build succeeded. Here is the screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with thr version of the nuget.exe 
Your package configuration is

> You can set set which nuget.exe version do you want to use.

[image]

> You can use the additional parameter 'verbosity' to get more detail
>   displayed in the output window.

**Nuget CLI reference:**

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference

---

the same error with the nuget version 3.5. Download the latest nuget version. I had the same error and I could solve it by changing the nuget version to version 4.

---

Comment: Note that the builds will continue to fail on the publish step though as long as the same version number is published in the repository. I found a solution and provided the answer.